# SQL Dynamic Function with potential multi parameter input

Tags: sql-server, function, sqlxml

We have an application which stores phone entries as XML in a SQL Database.

All items received a Unique RecId(BIGINT) PK, some other fields along with a field which contains the XML data.

The XML is stored as answers per question, which are down as "aFieldx" e.g. aField1, aField2, aField19...

I need to pull specific answers for SSRS or reporting purposes, and need a better way of doing it.

In the past we used the Views which the application makes per form, but this joins on so many uneccesary things and goes very slow now out data volumes are high.

So I have managed to make a function which pulls one answer direct from the XML where you pass the RecId and an aField number, so for aField1 it would be:

Funcction([RecId],1) which would work instantly, but I need something more dynamic where you can pass in several aField numbers like ([RecId],1,2,7,16) where this will then Pivot out into separate answers - Would this be done via a Table Valued Function?

Here's what I have so far, use the code to create an example to work with if required:

```
CREATE TABLE #PhoneDataTest(
    [RecID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Timetag1] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Timetag2] [datetime] NULL,
    [FormData] [xml] NULL
    )

INSERT INTO #PhoneDataTest
(
    [RecID],
    [Timetag1],
    [Timetag2],
    [FormData]

)
VALUES
(   35872909515,         -- RecID - bigint
    '2019-08-08 08:54:30.000', -- Timetag1 - datetime
    '2019-08-08 09:18:41.000', -- Timetag2 - datetime
    '<fd u="aa128cf6c82893aa" b="7" v="118">
  <field i="400">Form A</field>
  <field i="59">Testing Data</field>
  <field i="355">Semi Detached</field>
  <field i="36">Complete Meter Activity</field>
  <field i="441">No</field>
  <field i="37">Inside</field>
  <field i="493">No</field>
</fd>'     -- FormData - xml
    )
```

This is what I currently have to use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FieldXML]
(
@RecId BIGINT,
@aField NVARCHAR(1000)
)
returns NVARCHAR(1000)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @result as varchar(1000)

SET @result = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(FormData.query('/fd/field[@i=sql:variable("@aField")]') AS NVARCHAR(1000)),'<field i="'+@aField+'">',''),'</field>',''),'<field i="'+@aField+'"/>','') AS [Field]
               FROM #PhoneDataTest [pd]                                           
               WHERE [pd].[RecID] = @RecId)

return
@result

END
```

Used like this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_FieldXML](RecId,493), * FROM #PhoneDataTest
```

This will provide a value of "No" from the Field Answer 493

So my initial question will hopefully make sense now, how would I get ALL answers out by passing in just a RecId OR a set of answers by passing in a RecId and X number of aField numbers.

Any guidance would be appreciated, if it's possible anyway.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it correct - if you will get just  2 columns from your source xml, value of "i" attribute and  content of "field" element independently of "i"  value it will fit your needs?

Comment: The requirement could change depending which report is required from a Form; One may need aField1,2,4,6 and 10 coming back as a separate column, whereas another may only need aField1 and aField2.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FieldXML]
(
@RecId BIGINT,
@aField NVARCHAR(1000)
)
returns NVARCHAR(1000)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @result as varchar(1000)
DECLARE @FormData XML

SET @FormData = (SELECT pd.FormData
                 FROM PhoneDataTest [pd]                                           
                  WHERE [pd].[RecID] = @RecId)



    SET @result=(
                    SELECT T.valuea
                    FROM
                    (
                    SELECT Node.Data.value('.','varchar(50)') AS valuea,
                           Node.Data.value('@i','varchar(50)') AS Keys
                    FROM @FormData.nodes('/fd/field') Node(Data)
                    ) AS T
                    WHERE T.Keys=@aField
                )

return
@result

END

GO

SELECT [dbo].[fn_FieldXML](RecId,493), * FROM PhoneDataTest
```

Comment: I can see this does something very similar to my current Function, can this be changed to handle multiple inputs of the "aField"?

Comment: Yes, aFiled pass with comma separate value  '493','441' and user IN Clause WHERE T.Keys IN (@aField) function.

Comment: Thanks for the responses :) - I have tried to pass in multi and it returns NULL, do you have a working example?